# Build Python 2.7.12 on a Mac with Intel compiler

Tags: macos, python-2.7, build, intel

I've been trying to build Python from source on my mac with the Intel compiler suite (Intel Parallel Studio) and link it against Intel's MKL. 
The reason for that is that I want to use the exactly the same environment on my mac for developing Python code as on our linux cluster.

As long as I am not telling the configure script to use Intel's parallel studio, Python builds fine (configure and make: `./configure --with(out)-gcc`). But as soon as I include `--with-icc`, or if I set the appropriate environment variables, mentioned in `./configure --help`, to the Intel compilers and linkers, make fails with:

`icc -c -fno-strict-aliasing -fp-model strict -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g  -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/getcompiler.o Python/getcompiler.c`

`Python/getcompiler.c(27): error: expected a ";"
    return COMPILER;
           ^`

`compilation aborted for Python/getcompiler.c (code 2)
make: *** [Python/getcompiler.o] Error 2`

I've searched everywhere, but nobody seems to be interested in building Python on a mac with intel compilers, or I am the only one who has problems with it. I've also configured my environment according to Intel's instructions: `source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64`, in `~/.bash_profile`.

In any case, my environment is:

- OS X 10.11.6
- Xcode 8.1 / Build version 8B62
- Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017.0.036 (C/C++, Fortran)

Thanks,
François

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the line in `getcompiler.c` that it is complaining about:

e.g. to

`return "[Intel compiler]";`

If you wanted to get fancier you could add in the compiler version, using e.g. the `__INTEL_COMPILER` macro.